# Roles in django models

Tags: django, django-models, review

I have forgot Django and i was trying to write a model that will have 3 roles, staff individual and business. can someone review my code?
And can i make the code a bit cleaner?

lass Role(models.Model):

```
STAFF= 'staff'
INDIVIDUAL = 'individual'
BUSINESS = 'business'

ROLL_CHOICES =(
    (STAFF, 'staff'),
    (INDIVIDUAL, 'Individual'),
    (BUSINESS, 'Business'),
)

Role= models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=ROLL_CHOICES)
```

class Authuser(AbstractBaseUser):

```
role = models.CharField(choices=ROLL_CHOICES, primary_key=True)
email=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=155)
active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)   
admin=models.BooleanField(default=False)   
time_stamp=models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

USERNAME_FIELD='email'   
REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email']  

def get_first_name(self):      
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):      
    return self.email   
    
def __str__(self):      
    return self.email   
    
def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):      
    return True   

def has_module_perms(self,app_label):      
    return True   

    


@property

def is_admin(self):      
    "Is the user a admin member?"

    return self.admin   
@property

def is_active(self):      
    "Is the user active?"      

    return self.active
```

object=UserManager()

class Staff(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(Authuser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

class Business(models.Model):

```
Business_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(Authuser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
staff=models.BooleanField(default=False) 
KYC_docs=forms.FileField()
```

class Individual(models.Model):

```
staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
user = models.OneToOneField(Authuser, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
full_name=models.CharField(max_length=226)
address = models.TextField()
```

any input will be appreciated.